# How to mock and make HttpClientFactory return new httpClient when CreateClient

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to unit test a logic that would call API twice(the same API).

So I mock the httpClientFactory and httpClient.

But it would occur error when logic call API second time.

```
CLR/System.AggregateException
'System.AggregateException' at System.Private.CoreLib.dll 'One or more errors occurred.'
```

I think it may because after call API first, then the httpclient would release, so it would occur error when try to call second time.

I want to ask if I can make it return new HttpClient every time it call CreateClient?

Main Logic:

```
public ObjectRes MainLogic()
{
    var firstRes = GetObject("GetObjectInfo");
    //Do some process
    
    //After processing, get info again
    var result = GetObject("GetObjectInfo");
    return result;
}

private ObjectRes GetObject(string methodName)
{
    using var client = this.clientFactory.CreateClient(methodName);         
    var response = await client.SendAsync().Result; //would occur error when try get result
    var result = ObjectHelper.DeserializeJsonToObject<ObjectRes>(response.Content);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw new HttpRequestException(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Unit Test.cs

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(MainLogic_ShouldPass_TestCase))]
public void MainLogic_ShouldPass_TestCase(ObjectRes expectedResult)
{
    // Arrange
    var _httpClientFactory = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
    var client = new HttpClient(mockHttpMessageHandler.Object);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://1.1.1.1");
    _httpClientFactory.Setup(_ => _.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(client);

    IMainLogic _mainLogic = new MainLogic(_httpClientFactory.Object);

    // Act
    var result = _mainLogic.MainLogic();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
}
```

Comment: Don't guess; look at the aggregated errors contents in the debugger

Answer (score 2):

> I want to ask if I can make it return new HttpClient every time it call CreateClient?

Use a delegate in `Returns` that will be invoked every time the configured member is called

```
//...

_httpClientFactory
    .Setup(_ => _.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns((string s) => new HttpClient(mockHttpMessageHandler.Object) {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://1.1.1.1")
    });

//...
```

That done, the subject under test should actually be async and not mixing blocking calls that could cause deadlocks

```
public async Task<ObjectRes> MainLogic() {
    var firstRes = await GetObject("GetObjectInfo");
    //Do some process
    
    //After processing, get info again
    var result = await GetObject("GetObjectInfo");
    return result;
}

private async Task<ObjectRes> GetObject(string methodName) {
    using var client = this.clientFactory.CreateClient(methodName);         
    var response = await client.SendAsync(); //<--
    var result = ObjectHelper.DeserializeJsonToObject<ObjectRes>(response.Content);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        throw new HttpRequestException(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Along with the test as well

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(MainLogic_ShouldPass_TestCase))]
public async Task MainLogic_ShouldPass_TestCase(ObjectRes expectedResult) {
    // Arrange
    var _httpClientFactory = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
    _httpClientFactory
        .Setup(_ => _.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns((string s) => new HttpClient(mockHttpMessageHandler.Object) {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("http://1.1.1.1")
        });

    IMainLogic _mainLogic = new MainLogic(_httpClientFactory.Object);

    // Act
    var result = await _mainLogic.MainLogic();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
}
```

Assuming the `mockHttpMessageHandler` has been properly configured, the test case should behave as expected with the above refactor